# Git and usage of esformatter in react native project

Tags: javascript, git, react-native

I wanted to know how to make run esformatter to all js files changed in my git project before commiting.
If this is not possible, how to run esformatter to all js files.

This is my package json. I'm really new in devops. Any advice is appreciated but I really really want to achieve automated format before commiting. Thanks a lot!

```
{
      "name": "asdasda",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "precommit": "esformatter (to a changedfile using husky its possible?)"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@remobile/react-native-splashscreen": "^1.0.4",
        "babel-eslint": "^6.0.0",
        "eslint": "^3.13.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.9.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^2.2.1",
        "firebase": "^3.4.1",
        "husky": "^0.12.0",
        "moment": "^2.15.2",
        "react": "15.3.1",
        "react-native": "0.33.0"
      },
      "rnpm": {
        "assets": [
          "./assets"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "esformatter-jsx": "^7.4.1"
      },
      "esformatter": {
        "plugins": [
        "esformatter-jsx"
      ],
      // this is the section this plugin will use to store the settings for the jsx formatting 
      "jsx": {
        // whether to recursively format jsx expressions with esformatter 
        // set this to false if you don't want JSXExpressions to be formatted recursively, like when using problematic plugins 
        "formatJSXExpressions": true,
        // By default ObjectExpression and ArrayExpression in JSXExpressions are inlined, 
        // if false, the Expression might expand several lines 
        "JSXExpressionsSingleLine": true,
        // by default is true if set to false it works the same as esformatter-jsx-ignore 
        "formatJSX": true,
        // keep the node attributes on the same line as the open tag. Default is true. 
        // Setting this to false will put each one of the attributes on a single line 
        "attrsOnSameLineAsTag": true,
         // how many attributes should the node have before having to put each 
         // attribute in a new line. Default 1 
        "maxAttrsOnTag": 1,
        // if the attributes are going to be put each one on its own line, then keep the first 
        // on the same line as the open tag 
        "firstAttributeOnSameLine": false,
        // default to one space. Make it empty if you don't like spaces between JSXExpressionContainers 
        "spaceInJSXExpressionContainers": " ",
        // align the attributes with the first attribute (if the first attribute was kept on the same line as on the open tag) 
        "alignWithFirstAttribute": true,
        "htmlOptions": { // same as the ones passed to js-beautifier.html 
          "brace_style": "collapse",
          "indent_char": " ",
          "indent_size": 2,
          "max_preserve_newlines": 2,
          "preserve_newlines": true
          //wrap_line_length: 250 
        }
      }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A pre-commit [Git Hook](http://githooks.com/) is what you are looking for. I haven't tested this, but I think you need something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
EXIT_CODE=0

ESFORMATTER_ERRORS=$( esformatter src/**/*.js | tee )
if  [[ $ESFORMATTER_ERRORS ]]; then
    echo "$ESFORMATTER_ERRORS"
    EXIT_CODE=1
fi

exit $EXIT_CODE
```

Comment: Well I'm actually implementing git hooks with husky https://github.com/typicode/husky woof! so, I want to know how to implement a script for all js changed files before commiting them

Comment: How can  I list all changed files in a commit and apply esformatter to them?

Comment: This is how you list al changed files: `git diff --name-only HEAD~1 HEAD`. Use stdout in your shell script to pass them to your esformatter command.

Comment: That command gives me the last modified files from the last push?
I need the ones which I'm modifying (untracked files) It means (Changes to be committed:) and (Changes not staged for commit:) all of them which are js turn into formatted files